# Webform Localization

Tags: webforms

I created a form in English. I used the localization webform module to translate the fields of the form. In configuration -> Regional and Language -> Translate interface -> Translate. It works!

Now I'd like to translate different e-mails in several languages. For this I enabled the option: "Synchronize webform recipients e-mail across node translations."

Now what I need to do more? I wanted to set up E-mails with  confirmations in different languages or even use different email. I'm a little confused on this part.

Thank you for your help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a select field in your webform, for example ( language ) then you can filter emails using that select field. You can rather let the user select the language or do it with a language detection script.